# Android tab view with FragmentStageAdapter dynamic content

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, tabs, x509certificate

I am trying to implement a tabbed viewer by the use of FragmentStageAdapter, a Fragment and the android.support.v4.view.ViewPager framework. Each tab page shall display a X509 certificate (dynamic content), which was previously downloaded from the web.

The procedure i had in my mind is as follows:

- Download the certificates and store them in an array
- Populate the Tab activity with tabs, each tab contains a certificate

#### What is working:

- I can download the certificates and store them in an array.
- I can instantiate my FragmentActivity
- I can add the same amount of tabs as certificates in my array to the tab view

#### What is not working

After I have added all tabs, I call the method notifyDataSetChanged() of my FragmentStagePageAdapter, the debugger stops in the onCreateView method of my Fragement, when i try to infalte the Fragment

```
View certView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.certificate_view, container, false);
```

Afterwards I return while debugging back to the notifyDataSetChanged() method call and my eclipse debugger disconnects and throws the exception:

```
An internal error occurred during: "JDI Event Dispatch".
```

java.lang.NullPointerException

In the ADB logcat i can see the following exception occuring multiple times:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application android.app.Application: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to get package info for com.mydomain.mypackage; is package not installed?
```

I already tried to clean my project, uninstall the apk from my device but the error still remains.

Below I have listed some of my sources, I have shortened some of them for the sake of simplicity.

#### Questions

Is this the right way to populate Fragments within a tab view with "dynamic" data? As far as I understand, the FragementStagePageAdapter shall be used for an undetermined amound of tabs, instead of a FragementAdapter which is used for 'static' content.

Here is my **FragmentActivity**

```
public class MyFragmentActivity extends FragmentActivity {
public static final String ARGUMENT_SERVER_URL = "URL";
private String mHostUrl;

private X509Certificate[] mX509Certificates;

private MyFragmentStagePageAdapter mCertPageAdapter;
private ActionBar mActionBar;
private ViewPager mViewPager;

private OnPageChangeListener onPageChangeListener = 
new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener(){
    
    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        mActionBar = getActionBar();
        mActionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
    };
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle arg0) {
    super.onCreate(arg0);
    setContentView(R.layout.certificate_view_pager);
    
    // get the host url from the activity's received intent
    getHostUrlFromIntent();
    
    // instantiate the FragmentStatePagerAdapter 
    mCertPageAdapter = 
    new MyFragmentStagePageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    
    // create the ViewPager
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.certificate_view_pager);
    
    // assign a onPageChangeListener
    mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(onPageChangeListener);
    // set the FragmentStatePagerAdapter
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mCertPageAdapter);
    
    mActionBar = getActionBar();
    mActionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    
    startCertificateDownloadAsync();
}

private void getHostUrlFromIntent() {
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bundle serverCredentialsBundle = intent.getExtras();
    mHostUrl = serverCredentialsBundle.getString(ARGUMENT_SERVER_URL);
    if (mHostUrl == null) {
        throw new InvalidParameterException("URL must not be empty");
    }
}

private TabListener tabListener = new TabListener() {
    
    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        
    }
    
    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }
    
    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        
    }
};

private void startCertificateDownloadAsync(){
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>() {

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // retreive certificates here 
            // (code is removed for the sake of simplicity)

        }
        
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            assignCertificatesToActionBarOnUiThread();
        }
    }.execute();
}

private void assignCertificatesToActionBarOnUiThread() {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (mX509Certificates != null && 
            mX509Certificates.length >  0) {
                
                
                for (int i = 0; i < mX509Certificates.length; i++) {
                    Tab newTab = mActionBar.newTab();
                    X509Certificate cert = mX509Certificates[i];
                    newTab.setText(cert.getIssuerDN().getName());
                    newTab.setTabListener(tabListener);
                    mActionBar.addTab(newTab);
                }
                mCertPageAdapter.setCertificateArray(mX509Certificates);
                // call is required, when data was changed externally 
                mCertPageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
        
    });
}
```

Here is my **Fragment**

```
public class MyCertificateFragment extends Fragment {
public static final String ARG_CERT = "CERTIFICATE";

private X509Certificate certificate;

private TextView commonName;


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, 
        ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // The last two arguments ensure LayoutParams are inflated properly.
    View certView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.certificate_view, 
container, false);
    
    Activity activity = getActivity();
    commonName = (TextView) 
activity.findViewById(R.id.certViewTextViewCnValue);
    
    byte[] certificateBytes = 
savedInstanceState.getByteArray(LoginActivity.INTENT_EXTRA_CERTIFICATE);
    certificate = CertUtils.toX509Certificate(certificateBytes);
    
    commonName.setText(certificate.getSubjectX500Principal().getName());
    return certView;
}
}
```

This is how my **certificate_view.xml** looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/certificate_view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/certViewLinearLayoutCn"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="fill_vertical|fill_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/certViewTextViewCnLabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:text="Common Name:" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/certViewTextViewCnValue"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:text="" />

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Pager** activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/certificate_view_pager"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip
    android:id="@+id/pager_title_strip"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:background="#33b5e5"
    android:paddingBottom="4dp"
    android:paddingTop="4dp"
    android:textColor="#fff" />

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

The **FrameStagePageAdapter**

```
public class MyViewpageAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

private X509Certificate[] certificateArray;

public void setCertificateArray(X509Certificate[] array) {
    this.certificateArray = array;
}

public MyViewpageAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int i) {
    Fragment certFragment = null;
    if (i > -1 && i < certificateArray.length) {
        certFragment = new MyCertificateFragment();
        byte[] encodedCertificate = null;
        try {
            encodedCertificate = certificateArray[i].getEncoded();
        } catch (CertificateEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
        arguments.putByteArray(LoginActivity.INTENT_EXTRA_CERTIFICATE,
        encodedCertificate);
        certFragment.setArguments(arguments);
    }
    return certFragment;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    int count = 0;
    if (certificateArray != null){
        count = certificateArray.length;
    }
    return count;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue in my certificate_view.xml. There was an error in the layout. I had an empty height for a linear layout. Therefore the certificate_view.xml could not be loaded in the onCreateView method.